# compute $\limsup\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}$ ${l_{G,S} (k)}$ / ${l_{G,T} (k)}$ $<$ $ \infty$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. For a finite subset $S \subset G$ which generates $G$,

define $D_{G,S(n)}$ = {$s_1 s_2 ...s_r   \vert  s_i \in S \cup S^{-1} , r \le n  $}

$l_{G,S} (k)$ =  min {n  $\vert$ $\# D_{G,S(n)}$ $ \geq k $}

For any finite subsets $S,T\subset G$generating $G$,

show that $\limsup\limits_{k\rightarrow  \infty}$ ${l_{G,S} (k)}$ / ${l_{G,T} (k)}$ $<$ $ \infty$

$\liminf\limits_{k\rightarrow  \infty}$ $l_{G,S} (k)$ / ${l_{G,T} (k)}$ $>$  $0$

i cannot understand how to compute this. Can you give any hint or solution ?

Comment: If you have two generating sets, every element of one generating set is a word in elements of the othe generating set.

Comment: then $D_{G,S(n)}$ consist of words that the number of elements is less or equal than $n$.  thus set of words  whose length $\le n$ .      $l_{G,S} (k)$ is the minimum of $n$ satisfying the number of words whose length $\le n$ is  larger than $k$.

Comment: In the definition of $D_{G,S(n)}$ , $s_i ^{-1} \in S$ means that some $s \in S$  can be    $s_i ^{-1} \not\in S$ ? then when $n=1$ , can  $D_{G,S(1)}$ be strictly less than $S$

Comment: thank you for your comment, when i exhausted for understanding math problem, i wrote problem so i'm sorry for so poor description .  i  really appreciate your help for reading my problem  and giving some hint, i keep trying to understand this problem thank you

Comment: The definition of $D_{G,S(n)}$ is still wrong. At the moment it could be the empty set for all $n$. I think you want $s_i \in S$ OR $s_i^{-1} \in S$ (which is often written as $s_i \in S \cup S^{-1}$).

Comment: Thank you.  i fixed it.

Comment: To expand on Charlie Frohman's hint, choose $m$ such that every element of $S$ can be expressed as word of length at most $m$ over $T \cup T^{-1}$, and the same with $T$ and $S$ reversed. Then $1/m \le l_{G,S}(k)/l_{G,T}(k) \le m$ for all $k$.

Comment: I understand  one can choose such a m, but i confuse $l_{G,S} (k)/l_{G,T}(k) \le m $. Could you explain  more about this $l_{G,S} (k)/l_{G,T}(k) \le m $?